# Expiring sessions with Lumen 5.2 and JWT

Tags: jwt, lumen

I'm currently creating a CRUD api in Lumen 5.2 and want to add token authorization to it.

To make this work i found a package called tymondesigns/jwt-auth.
But after every day my users sign out.

Can i prolong this to lets say a month ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use ttl feature of this package ? 
It is your tokens live span.

In your config/jwt.php search for this line, and adjust the ttl accordingly.

```
'ttl' => 43800, // a month
```

Be sure to look at their wiki
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Installation
All information is there.